# Odd behavior when running a PowerShell script from CMD

Tags: powershell

I have been experiencing differences in behavior when running a PowerShell script in the ISE and from a CMD prompt.

The purpose of the script is to check for active alerts for Microsoft's DPM (Data Protection Management) service. If it finds something older than 12 hours it logs an error in the 'DPM Alerts' event log.

I developed the script in the ISE, and it seemed to work perfectly. So I added it to *Scheduled tasks*, where it wasn't doing what I wanted. I eventually stripped out the logic that tested for age of the alert, so that all I was doing was trying to get a list of current active alerts.

```
$serverName = "my_server_name"

$dpmServer = Connect-DPMServer $serverName
$dpmServer.AlertController.RefreshAlerts()
$activeAlerts = $dpmServer.AlertController.ActiveAlerts

if  (!$activeAlerts) {"no active alerts found"}
else {$activeAlerts}
```

I'm loading the DPM snap-in via a PSConsoleFile. The command I'm executing from CMD looks like this:

```
 powershell -psconsole .\DPMConsoleFile.psc1 -file .\DPMAlertChecker.ps1�
```

�

I know that the snap-in is loading correctly, because if I include a line that just shows the $dpmServer object, it shows the correct information.

If I run this from the PowerShell ISE (or DPM Management Shell), it works just fine and shows a list of active alerts (if any). If I run it from a command line using the above syntax, it doesn't work. Specifically, it doesn't return any alerts from the `$dpmServer.alertcenter.activealerts` command.

What is the difference?

Comment: If this works from ISE then I would think that it would work without using the PSC1 (console) file.  Are you manually loading the snapin in ISE?  It might be best to just add the snapin as part of the script.

Comment: I found the issue. It looks like there is a slight delay between connecting to the dpm server using Connect-DPMServer and when you can see alerts. I added a loop to the effect of while (!$alerts) and within the loop ran refreshAlerts() and alertController.ActiveAlerts. After about 10 seconds, I was able to see and act on the active alerts. When running it in the ISE, the variables persisted between runs, so there was enough time for the connection to happen. When invoked using "powershell -file scriptname", the shell exited before the connection could happen.

Comment: Fine, can you put your comment as the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It looks like there is a slight delay between connecting to the DPM server using `Connect-DPMServer` and when you can see alerts.

I added a loop to the effect of `while (!$alerts)` and within the loop ran `refreshAlerts()` and `alertController.ActiveAlerts`. After about 10 seconds, I was able to see and act on the active alerts.

When running it in the ISE, the variables persisted between runs, so there was enough time for the connection to happen. When invoked using "powershell -file scriptname", the shell exited before the connection could happen.